# Is there any parameters for google navigation?

Tags: android, dictionary, navigation

To launch google navigation from map,
I know using Intent like **"google.navigation:q=somewhere"** on map view.
but google navigation suggested the route to use highways and tolls.

I want the route without using them.
I tried **avoid=highways** and **avoid=tolls** option, but it didn't work.
Is there any options to do that?